# Java heap space consuming with JTable char[], String and Objects

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jvm, heap-memory

I'm trying to understand better and improve the memory usage of my Swing application.

There is a screen which the user tends to open repeatedly every time he needs to search a product to sell. This screen shows a jtable with lots of products as shown in the figure below.

[image]

The problem is that when I keep opening and closing this screen, heap memory keeps increasing and the garbage collector seems not to be working (probably because my objects are not being freed).

I used java VisualVM to check which objects are most consuming the heap space and the screenshot below shows it.

[image]

I suppose that these char[] and string objects are being created because of the JTable.

When I close the screen, I do the following

```
jTable1 = null;
data = null; //(arraylist where I stored the data from the database)
System.gc();
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I might be missing? Is there another way to free objects besides setting references to null?

Thanks for helping!

Code for structuring the data into an object[][] to put in the table.

```
private Object[][] getProdutosObjects() {
        ProdutoModel pm = new ProdutoModel();
        try {
            data = pm.getAllProducts();
        } catch (DefaultException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMsg(), "", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }

        Object[][] matriz = new Object[data.size()][3];
        int i = 0;
        for (Object p : data) {
            matriz[i][0] = ((Object[])p)[0]; //codigodist
            matriz[i][1] = ((Object[])p)[1]; //descricao
            matriz[i][2] = ((Object[])p)[2]; //descricaodist
            i++;
        }

        return matriz;
    }
```

Code for creating the jtable:

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                getProdutosObjects(),
                new String [] {
                    "Código", "Descrição", "Descrição Distribuidor"
                }
        ){
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                    true, false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {  
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {  
                jTable1.scrollRectToVisible(jTable1.getCellRect(  
                        jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0, true));  
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to translate from `data` to `Object[][]`.  If you used an `AbstractTableModel` instead, you could gain finer control over what and how data is returned by the model

Comment: Yea.. I think that would be a better choice in order to perform less operations while creating the JTable. I tried it now and created my own Model using directly my List data, but the problem remains. It keeps initializing all that char[], Strings and Integers objects and they don't get freed from memory.

Comment: You can use JVisualVM to view individual objects of a particular type, then look at their incoming references.  This will tell you what's keeping the objects alive.

Answer (score 0):

Make Weak or soft references objects so that GC will clear the references after reaching certain threshold cycles.